# Does Io have an equivalent to C's exit(signal) function?

Tags: io, signals, exit, terminate

If the C code is:

```
exit(0);
```

I imagine the Io code would look something like:

```
0 exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exit` seems to work, though it doesn't offer a way to signal an error.